# How to move characters from right to left of string

Tags: ruby, string, reverse, move

I need to move characters from left to right of a string in combinations of two. An example input is:

```
"D21635D486450000C1"
```

The expected output for this is:

```
"C100004586D43516D2"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have this so far:

```
str = "D21635D486450000C1"
str.length.times do |i|
 str.insert(i, str[-2-i])
end
puts str
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you provide more detail?

Comment: not quite, so this is my string "D21635D486450000C1" i just need to reverse it in combinations of two, ill space the string out in two's so you get the idea.
needs to look like this basically but with no spaces, i only did this to show you
C1 00 00 45 86 D4 35 16 D2

Comment: Ah i see what you mean now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"D21635D486450000C1".chars.each_slice(2).to_a.reverse.join
#⇒ "C100004586D43516D2"
```

or use `join(' ')` on the last step to have spaces or whatever between slices.

---

Also:

```
str = "D21635D486450000C1"
(0..str.length-1).step(2).map { |i| [str[-i-2], str[-i-1]] }.join
#⇒ "C100004586D43516D2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"D21635D486450000C1"
.reverse.gsub(/(.)(.)/, '\2\1')
#=> "C100004586D43516D2"

"D21635D486450000C1"
.reverse.gsub(/../, &:reverse)
#=> "C100004586D43516D2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"D21635D486450000C1".scan(/.{1,2}/).reverse.join
#=> "C100004586D43516D2"
```